# Como ler XML no padrão do viva real?

Tags: php, xml

Tenho um sistema imobiliário e com isso desenvolvi meu próprio padrão XML para integração com Portais.

Mas o código que utilizo para fazer a leitura do meu XML, não consegue fazer a leitura que está no padrão do Viva Real.

Segue exemplo do padrão Viva Real:

```
<ListingDataFeed xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vivareal.com/schemas/1.0/VRSync">
<Header>
<PublishDate>2016-04-07T11:32:06</PublishDate>
<Provider>Agencia ArteDB</Provider>
<Email>joaci@artedb.com.br</Email>
<ContactName>Joaci Brito</ContactName>
<Telephone>(11) 982013467</Telephone>
<Logo>http://artedb.com.br/images/logo.png</Logo>
</Header>
<Listings>
<Listing>
<ListingID> 006</ListingID>
<Featured>true</Featured>
<ListDate>2016-01-21T01:51:08</ListDate>
<LastUpdateDate>2016-01-21T01:51:08</LastUpdateDate>
<TransactionType>For Sale</TransactionType>
<Title>Sobrado - Venda - Alvorada </Title>
<Location>
<Country abbreviation="BR">Brasil</Country>
<State abbreviation="SP">São Paulo</State>
<City>Guarulhos</City>
<Neighborhood>Alvorada </Neighborhood>
<PostalCode>07000-000</PostalCode>
<Zone>Zona Leste</Zone>
<Url>http://www.brunaalbuquerqueimoveis.com.br/detalharimovel.php?imovel=52d96ce4cba0c7.93798</Url>
<Latitude>-23.4444658</Latitude>
<Longitude>-46.4153649</Longitude>
</Location>
<Details>
<Description>Sobrado :: 3 Dorm. ( sendo um suite, mais dois dorm. um com sacada + banheiro para auxiliar os dormitórios solteiros), sala ( dois ambientes), lavabo, copa/cozinha, área de serv.no fundo coberta com amplo espaço no fundo para lazer + 2 vagas de garagem. Bairro com Toda Infraestrutura, proximo a escolas, farmácias, padaria e hospital, fácil acesso as avenidas principais e rodovia Presidente Dutra.  :: Obs.: Aceita Financiamento Pela Caixa Econômica ou qualquer outro banco de sua preferencia 
</Description>
<ListPrice currency="BRL">350000</ListPrice>
<PropertyAdministrationFee currency="BRL">0</PropertyAdministrationFee>
<PropertyType>Residential / Home</PropertyType>
<ConstructedArea unit="square metres">0</ConstructedArea>
<Bedrooms>3</Bedrooms>
<Bathrooms>2</Bathrooms>
<Suites>1</Suites>
<Garage type="Parking Space">2</Garage>
<LotArea unit="square metres">0</LotArea>
<Features/>
</Details>
<Media>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab120776a80.01.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab499d69c19.05.jpg</Item><Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab5af593342.20.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab71461d604.66.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab8088f8392.44.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab8e877d475.37.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab976adf8f1.69.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ababd986a19.88.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535abb3c3b2420.52.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535abe736cb462.06.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ac10e808778.82.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ac28431e507.25.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ac3686a7c20.81.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ac46ee16e91.39.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ac8b0944b01.72.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535acb37dae581.87.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535af0cf037f16.70.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535af2e7b68645.33.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535af56bc1aa27.12.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535af6b0bbc383.26.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535af8354bb722.99.jpg</Item>
</Media>
<ContactInfo>
<Email>imobiliarianovauniao@gmail.com</Email>
<Name>Imobiliária Nova União</Name>
<Telephone>2087-0293</Telephone>
<Website>brunaalbuquerqueimoveis.com.br</Website>
<Location>
<Country abbreviation="BR">Brasil</Country>
<State>SP</State>
</Location>
</ContactInfo>
<Status>
<PropertyStatus>Available</PropertyStatus>
<StatusDate>2016-01-21T01:51:08</StatusDate>
</Status>
</Listing>
</ListingDataFeed>
```

Agora segue o código PHP que utilizo para ler o XML que desenvolvi dentro do meu padrão e que funciona perfeitamente, mas não captura os campos do XML que está no padrão do Viva Real acima:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('roteirodoimovel.xml');
// transformar o XML em um objeto
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
// iteracao por todo o XML:
foreach ($sxml as $linhaAtual) {
// obter cada item do xml referente ao campo da tabela
// cast porque a propriedade do objeto
// tambem é um objeto do tipo SimpleXMLElement

$id = (int) $linhaAtual->id;
$goal = (int) $linhaAtual->goal;
$idimv = (int) $linhaAtual->idimv; 
$url = (string) $linhaAtual->url; 
$urlimovel = (string) $linhaAtual->urlimovel; 
$agency_name = (string) $linhaAtual->agency_name; 
$agency_email = (string) $linhaAtual->agency_email; 
$logo = (string) $linhaAtual->logo; 
$type = (string) $linhaAtual->type; 
$property_type = (string) $linhaAtual->property_type; 
$title = (string) $linhaAtual->title; 
$content = (string) $linhaAtual->content; 
$rooms = (int) $linhaAtual->rooms; 
$bathrooms = (int) $linhaAtual->bathrooms; 
$parking = (int) $linhaAtual->parking; 
$floor_area = (string) $linhaAtual->floor_area; 
$price = (int) $linhaAtual->price; 
$region = (string) $linhaAtual->region; 
$city = (string) $linhaAtual->city; 
$country = (string) $linhaAtual->country; 
$neighborhood = (string) $linhaAtual->neighborhood; 
$address = (string) $linhaAtual->address; 
$picture_url = (string) $linhaAtual->picture_url;
```

O que fazer para que ele leia os padrões do Viva Real?

Answer (score 2):

Ontem mesmo eu estava trabalhando com isso.
Tente essa fução abaixo.
Ela vai receber o path ate o seu xml, vai taravessar os nós e vai retornar uma array em php.
Dai fica fácil para vc manipular.
Nota: o Seu xml tem que ser válido, ou seja, estar bem formatado, seguindo as normas de criação de xml. Caso contrário a função simplexml_load_file e serialize não irão reconhecer os nós.

```
    private function get_XML_Content($xml_Name_Path) {          
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_Name_Path);
        $xml_arr_Content = unserialize(serialize(json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), 1)));  
        return $xml_arr_Content;
    }




//Display sua array no browser:  
$arrXML = function get_XML_Content($o_camilho_ate_seu_XML);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrXML);
echo "</pre>";
```

E o seu padrão xml tem um erro na tag `<Listings>`.
Se vc retirá-la vai conseguir ler o arquivo com a função acima.

Veja o resultado do meu teste:

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [schemaLocation] => http://www.vivareal.com/schemas/1.0/VRSync
        )

    [Header] => Array
        (
            [PublishDate] => 2016-04-07T11:32:06
            [Provider] => Agencia ArteDB
            [Email] => joaci@artedb.com.br
            [ContactName] => Joaci Brito
            [Telephone] => (11) 982013467
            [Logo] => http://artedb.com.br/images/logo.png
        )

    [Listing] => Array
        (
            [ListingID] =>  006
            [Featured] => true
            [ListDate] => 2016-01-21T01:51:08
            [LastUpdateDate] => 2016-01-21T01:51:08
            [TransactionType] => For Sale
            [Title] => Sobrado - Venda - Alvorada 
            [Location] => Array
                (
                    [Country] => Brasil
                    [State] => SÃ£o Paulo
                    [City] => Guarulhos
                    [Neighborhood] => Alvorada 
                    [PostalCode] => 07000-000
                    [Zone] => Zona Leste
                    [Url] => http://www.brunaalbuquerqueimoveis.com.br/detalharimovel.php?imovel=52d96ce4cba0c7.93798
                    [Latitude] => -23.4444658
                    [Longitude] => -46.4153649
                )

            [Details] => Array
                (
                    [Description] => Sobrado :: 3 Dorm. ( sendo um suite, mais dois dorm. um com sacada + banheiro para auxiliar os dormitÃ³rios solteiros), sala ( dois ambientes), lavabo, copa/cozinha, Ã¡rea de serv.no fundo coberta com amplo espaÃ§o no fundo para lazer + 2 vagas de garagem. Bairro com Toda Infraestrutura, proximo a escolas, farmÃ¡cias, padaria e hospital, fÃ¡cil acesso as avenidas principais e rodovia Presidente Dutra.  :: Obs.: Aceita Financiamento Pela Caixa EconÃ´mica ou qualquer outro banco de sua preferencia 

                    [ListPrice] => 350000
                    [PropertyAdministrationFee] => 0
                    [PropertyType] => Residential / Home
                    [ConstructedArea] => 0
                    [Bedrooms] => 3
                    [Bathrooms] => 2
                    [Suites] => 1
                    [Garage] => 2
                    [LotArea] => 0
                    [Features] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [Media] => Array
                (
                    [Item] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab120776a80.01.jpg
                            [1] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab499d69c19.05.jpg
                            [2] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab5af593342.20.jpg
                            [3] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab71461d604.66.jpg
                            [4] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab8088f8392.44.jpg
                            [5] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab8e877d475.37.jpg
                            [6] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ab976adf8f1.69.jpg
                            [7] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ababd986a19.88.jpg
                            [8] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535abb3c3b2420.52.jpg
                            [9] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535abe736cb462.06.jpg
                            [10] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ac10e808778.82.jpg
                            [11] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ac28431e507.25.jpg
                            [12] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ac3686a7c20.81.jpg
                            [13] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ac46ee16e91.39.jpg
                            [14] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535ac8b0944b01.72.jpg
                            [15] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535acb37dae581.87.jpg
                            [16] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535af0cf037f16.70.jpg
                            [17] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535af2e7b68645.33.jpg
                            [18] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535af56bc1aa27.12.jpg
                            [19] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535af6b0bbc383.26.jpg
                            [20] => http://eclipse.artedb.com.br/arquivos/img2/IMO535af8354bb722.99.jpg
                        )

                )

            [ContactInfo] => Array
                (
                    [Email] => imobiliarianovauniao@gmail.com
                    [Name] => ImobiliÃ¡ria Nova UniÃ£o
                    [Telephone] => 2087-0293
                    [Website] => brunaalbuquerqueimoveis.com.br
                    [Location] => Array
                        (
                            [Country] => Brasil
                            [State] => SP
                        )

                )

            [Status] => Array
                (
                    [PropertyStatus] => Available
                    [StatusDate] => 2016-01-21T01:51:08
                )

        )

)
```